# Assigning a variable via jQuery.fn.data() will keep a reference to the original tag value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Considering the following html:

```
<div id="test" data-test='["foo", "bar"]'></div>
```

and the following javascript:

```
var dataValue = jQuery('#test').data('test');
dataValue.splice(0,1);
```

I will then have the following results:

```
dataValue
['bar']         // as expected, i'm fine with that


jQuery('#test').data('test')
['bar']         // why ? i would expect ['foo', 'bar']
```

This might be something really basic I don't understand with javascript itself or jQuery but I'd be happy if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but `dataValue.concat().splice(0,1);` will create a copy of the array or slice for that matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript uses references. This means:

```
[1] !== [1]; // two separate objects
```

but:

```
var arr = [1];
$(elem).data('test', arr)
$(elem).data('test') === arr; // same object again, jQuery respects references
```

I prefer looking at it as chocolate bars ( :-) ). Two chocolate bars are never the same. If you eat one, the other still has 100% left. But if you only have one chocolate bar, and you eat it, put that bar away and fetch it back some time later, you'll obtain that very same (eaten) chocolate bar.

So what I want to say is that when calling `.splice`, it is modifying that very same array.

Answer (score 1):

`dataValue.splice(0,1)` changes the array *in-place* and `data` still has the reference to that array. It does not create a copy of the array.

It is the same as if you do:

```
var dataValue = ['foo', 'bar'];
jQuery('#test').data('test', dataValue);

dataValue.splice(0,1);    
console.log(jQuery('#test').data('test'));
```